# Linear system of equations, but determinant is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I am using the determinant method of solving a system of linear equations, what if the determinant is zero?

Comment: Then there won't be a unique solution.

Comment: If you mean [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) for square systems (as many unknowns as equations), then the answer is: you don't... It's only valid for non-singular systems (i.e. with a unique solution).

Answer (score 4):

I assume you refer to the determinant of the matrix of all the coëfficients. It means that there is either no solution or an infinitude of solutions.